# SQL - grabbing rows with two conditions but excluding everything else

Tags: sql

Say you have a
column called `service_id`.
There are multiple instances of this. (its not unique).

And theirs a another column- `product code` with a bunch of them.

So we have
I have to select 2 additional colums (not related to product code or id) in the select statement? I get an "Selected non aggregate values must be apart of asociated group?

---

```
service id:   Product Code: 
1             dog
1             cat
1             mouse
2             dog
2             cat
3             mouse
```

---

I want to pull only the service id's that have product codes of dog & cat ONLY, but nothing else.
so if service id has a mouse also, i don't want to include that.

In this case i would only want to pull service id 2, since it only has dog cat.

How can i write this in SQL?

We want only ids that have cat & mouse but nothing else.

Comment: Can you share your DBMS you're currently using and your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: Is the combination of `service_id` **and** `product_code` unique?

Comment: First you say "*dog & cat ONLY, but nothing else*" But then "*only ids that have cat & mouse but nothing else*".

Comment: The second one is a probable typo in the description. @PM77-1

Comment: @lemon - probably, but OP has to fix.

Answer (score 2):

You may use conditional aggregation as the following:

```
select serviceId from table_name
group by serviceId
having count(case when ProductCode not in ('cat','dog') then 1 end)=0
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/rL25yGtC).

If you want to ensure that 'serviceId' has a dog **AND** cat you may try the following:

```
select serviceId from table_name
group by serviceId
having count(case when ProductCode not in ('cat','dog') then 1 end)=0
       and count(case when ProductCode ='cat' then 1 end)>0
       and count(case when ProductCode ='dog' then 1 end)>0
```

Comment: Ok but what if i have to select 2 additional colums with id (not related to product code or id) in the select statement? I get an "Selected non aggregate values must be apart of asociated group?

Comment: You can join this query with your table to get any additional columns, [check this](https://dbfiddle.uk/iiYqZclP)

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd have done it is to `SELECT` the invalid IDs separately:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT service_id
FROM product
WHERE service_id NOT IN (
  select service_id
  from product
  where product_code not in ('cat', 'dog')
)
```

and make the second select into a CTE if it's any more complicated than that.

But Ahmed's solution is more flexible and expressive, I think.